A Property of Projection Matrices
For two orthogonal projection matrices $P_0$ and $P_1$, where $P_1\preceq P_0$ which means $P_0-P_1$ is a PSD matrix, I want to show that $P_0P_1P_0=P_1$. Any ideas?

Since $P_1\preceq P_0$ we have $P_0P_1P_0\preceq P_0$. I tried to also show that $P_0\preceq P_0P_1P_0$ but does not seem to be woking!

I added some explanation. What do you mean by invariant subspace? @CalvinLin

So the invariant subspace of a projection $P$ is the set of eigenvectors of $P$ with eigenvalue 1?@CalvinLin

Thanks!@CalvinLin

@CalvinLin A projection matrix is not uniquely defined by it's invariant subspace, i.e. it's image: we can have different projections with the same image. Consider $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$: both have $\begin{pmatrix}x\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ as the invariant subspace.

@lisyarus Oh dang it.

I did. @user1551

Note that the counterexample given above is ruled out by the orthogonal condition. So this proviso seems to resuscitate @CalvinLin's line of logic.

One possible approach: prove that $P_1P_0=P_1$.

@Semiclassical For what it's worth, the orthogonal condition appeared only after I wrote my comment about uniqueness.

Write $V = \ker P_0 \oplus \text{image }P_0$ and argue this decomposition is $P_1$-invariant:
(i.) the fact that $P_0-P_1\succeq \mathbf 0\implies \ker P_0 \subseteq \ker P_1\implies P_1\cdot \ker P_0 =\big\{\mathbf 0\big\}\subseteq \ker P_0$
(ii).    Now argue that since $P_1$ is real symmetric (or Hermitian) it follows that $ P_1\cdot \text{image }P_0\subseteq \text{image } P_0$.
Then for $v\in \ker P_0$:
$P_0P_1P_0v=\mathbf 0 = P_1v$
And for $v\in \text{image } P_0$:
$P_0P_1P_0v=P_0\big(P_1v\big) = P_1v$
$\implies P_0P_1P_0 = P_1$
Corollary: $\big(P_0-P_1\big)$ is an orthogonal projection

as a hint for OP on $\text{image }P_0$ being $P_1$-invariant: suppose we select $Q\in O_n(\mathbb R)$ with the first $r$ columns being a basis for $\ker P_0$ and the remaining columns being a basis for $\text{image }P_0$.  If $P_1Q = Q B$ what must $B$ look like?

Since $P_1$ is an orthogonal projection, there exists an orthogonal matrix $R$ such that $R^tP_1R=\begin{pmatrix}I_r&0\cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.
Now, $R^tP_0R, R^tP_1R$ are still orthogonal projections, and that $R^t(P_0-P_1)R$ is still PSD.
Replacing $P_0,P_1$ by $R^tP_0R, R^tP_1R$ if necessary, one may assume without loss of generality that $P_1=\begin{pmatrix}I_r&0\cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.
Since $P_0$ is an orthogonal projection, $P_0$ is symmetric.
Write $P_0=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\cr B^t & D\end{pmatrix},$ where $A,D$ are symmetric.
Since $P_0-P_1$ is a PSD, so is $A-I_r$. Now, $P_0P_1P_0=\begin{pmatrix}A^2&AB\cr (AB)^t & B^tB\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}I_r&0\cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.
Hence $A^2=I_r$, $AB=0$ and $B^tB=0$. Since $A^2=I_r$, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $-1$, with mutiplicities $t$ and $n-t$ respectively, so the eigenvalues of $A-I$ are $0$ and $-2$, with multiplicites $t$ and $n-t$. Since $A-I$ is a PSD, it means that $n-t=0$, meaning that $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$. But $A$ is symmetric , hence diagonalizable, so finally $A=I_r$.
Since $AB=0$, we get $B=0$.
Consequently, $P_0P_1P_0=\begin{pmatrix}I_r&0\cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}=P_1$.

What is the justification for writing "Now, $P_0P_1P_0=\begin{pmatrix}A^2&AB\cr (AB)^t & B^tB\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}I_r&0\cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$"?  The first equality follows by calculation; if the second equality has justification then you can stop your post right there as the problem is then solved since $\begin{pmatrix}I_r&0\cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}=P_1$.  From what I see you assert "Now, $P_0P_1P_0=\dots=\begin{pmatrix}I_r&0\cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$" to conclude "Consequently $P_0P_1P_0=\begin{pmatrix}I_r&0\cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}=P_1$" which is circular.

You're right.  @Nick Cooper, can you "untick" my answer , so I can delete it ?
